# device bypassing the FRP even frpAdminEmails are set in the Policy

Tags: android-management-api, android-work-profile

Utilizing the Android Management API with frpAdminEmails incorporated into policies.

I've successfully enrolled devices and applied various policies. However, despite having specified frpAdminEmails in the policy, after performing a factory reset on the device, it isn't prompting for the associated email, device is bypassing the FRP.

Any advice or insights on why the frpAdminEmails aren't being enforced after a factory reset?

I applied this sample policy

```
        'applications': [
            {
                'packageName': 'com.google.samples.apps.iosched',
                'installType': 'FORCE_INSTALLED',
            },
            {
                'packageName': 'com.google.android.apps.work.clouddpc',
                'autoUpdateMode': 'AUTO_UPDATE_HIGH_PRIORITY'
            }
        ],
        'locationMode': 'LOCATION_DISABLED',
        'frpAdminEmails': [myMailId, rpMailId],
```

I can even see that proper mailIds as frpAdminEmails when I fetch the policy or the device details.

Have tried with multiple devices, able to bypass FRP even when the policy have `frpAdminEmails`